# Proper program flow in a 3-tier design when logging in

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This code is used to log a user in. Initially I was happy with this, but I'd like to clean it up a bit. The lines in question are:

```
HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();
return selectedUser;
```

The problem is that the return statement doesn't execute until after the form is closed. So far I haven't run into any problems, but It looks incorrect. I call this method from a presentation layer class. Any suggestions?

```
  public static Account selectUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        Account selectedUser = new Account();
        if (sConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = sConnection.CreateCommand();
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE ([userName]='" + userName + "' AND [Password]='" + password + "')";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                if (dbReader.HasRows)
                {
                    selectedUser.custID = (int)dbReader[0];
                    selectedUser.firstName = (string)dbReader[1];
                    selectedUser.lastName = (string)dbReader[2];
                    selectedUser.phoneNum = (string)dbReader[3];
                    selectedUser.custEmail = (string)dbReader[4];
                    selectedUser.userName = (string)dbReader[5];
                    selectedUser.password = (string)dbReader[6];
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
                    HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
                    hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();
                    return selectedUser;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please say you know about SQL injection attacks, and that you're dealing with them?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of parameters. No one will touch this but me, it's just a small project.

Comment: IMO, it's that thought process that leads to infringement later down the road. Not accounting for injection attacks in personal projects is a good indicator that you're not comfortable with the process. Getting comfortable with it will make it faster, and make it natural.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, that's exactly right, ***practice how you will play or you'll play how you practice!***

Comment: Something else to consider: If this is a desktop app, then on the .NET platform, you'll probably be authenticating with the user's Active Directory credentials. If it's a web app, then you'll want to make sure that you're not tossing around the user's plaintext password. At the very least salt and MD5 it, better yet, BCrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you correct this is really determined by how the rest of your application is laid out. Probably the simplest thing to do would be to move the

```
HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();
```

lines to wherever `.selectUser()` is being called and make them conditional on the return value of `.selectUser()` being not null.

You could also create a custom LoginEvent class, and then fire a "LoginSuccess" or "LoginFail" event, that could be picked up by a UI Controller class that in turn creates your `HotelSearchForm`.

Comment: So would something like this work? I need to look up how to check for a null object I suppose.
if(selectedUser.findAUser != null)
{
MessageBox.Show("Success");
}

Comment: from inside the `.selectUser()` method, then yes, you could do `if(selectedUser != null) { MessageBox.Show("Success"); }`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you. I have learned a new technique as well! :)

Answer (score 2):

So I think it's *okay*, but here:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE ([userName]='" + userName + "' AND [Password]='" + password + "')";
```

you're going to want to change that to:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE ([userName]= @username AND [Password]= @password";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", userName);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", password);
```

to prevent SQL Injection attacks. Further, you have this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();
return selectedUser;
```

running while the `OleDbDataReader` is open, let's not do that, it's holding a connection open while that screen is up and that's just not good practice. Let's change it a little -because you need to dispose of that reader too:

```
bool success = false;
string error = null;

using (OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    try
    {
        while (dbReader.Read())
        {
            if (dbReader.HasRows)
            {
                selectedUser.custID = (int)dbReader[0];
                selectedUser.firstName = (string)dbReader[1];
                selectedUser.lastName = (string)dbReader[2];
                selectedUser.phoneNum = (string)dbReader[3];
                selectedUser.custEmail = (string)dbReader[4];
                selectedUser.userName = (string)dbReader[5];
                selectedUser.password = (string)dbReader[6];

                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error = e.ToString();
    }
}

if (success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
    HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
    hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();

    return selectedUser;
}

MessageBox.Show(error);
return null;
```

see here the `using` statement is going to ensure that the `OleDbDataReader` gets disposed of properly. ***You really need to build and wrap the `OleDbConnection` inside a `using` like that too.***

And really, these two lines:

```
while (dbReader.Read())
{
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
```

could be turned into:

```
if (dbReader.Read())
{
    ...
}
```

And one final note, ***it appears you're sharing a connection -`sConnection`***, please **do not do that**, build the connection, use it, and get rid of it. Take note to the below `using` statement:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    c.Open();
}
```

that's how an `IDbConnection` should be used -whether that be a `SqlConnection` or `OleDbConnection`.

**Oh, and one more thing,** if that `OleDbConnection` is connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server get rid of it and use the `SqlConnection` object. There are massive performance and memory usage differences in the two classes.

## Edit for comment by OP...

If you want the `return` to occur **before** the form is closed then use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` -however, if you're going to do that, I wouldn't recommend building and launching that form inside this method because this method's memory won't be able to be garbage collected until that form closes. I would recommend having a static class that can launch any form and call that, maybe something like this:

```
public static class FormManager
{
    public static void ShowForm(Type t)
    {
        var f = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        ((Form)f).Show();
    }
}
```

and then you could call that like this:

```
FormManager.ShowForm(typeof(HotelSearchForm));
```

in the place of these two lines:

```
HotelSearchForm hotelsearchForm = new HotelSearchForm();
hotelsearchForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: An excellent way to handle this, but I still don't get the "selectedUser" returned until the form is closed. I will make some of the changes you suggested.

Comment: @user1729696, the `selectedUser` isn't returned until the form is closed because you use `ShowDialog` -use `Show` instead if you want it to behave that way.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to recommend using `if (dbReader.Read())` instead of `while` since only one row is expected.  The `HasRows` shouldn't to needed here.

Comment: Excellent suggestions, I know that I am probably not using the most efficient code to communicate with my database. I appreciate you offering your help. :)